# Apache Pig String Split

Tags: apache-pig

I'm working with Pig STRSPLIT and having trouble working with fairly complex previously decoded strings.

Here is my data (chararray, chararray):

```
(test_term,category_facet=SAAS~All Products~pcmcat367^features_facet=Features~ENERGY STAR^brand_facet=Brand~GE)
```

Here is my code:

```
c3 = FOREACH c2 GENERATE search_term
,STRSPLIT(encoded, '\\^', -1) as facets_array
,day;
dump c3;
```

Here is my current output of c3:

```
(test_term,(category_facet=SAAS~All Refrigerators~pcmcat367,features_facet=Features~ENERGY STAR,brand_facet=Brand~GE))
```

Here is my desired output:

```
test_term, category, SAAS~All Products~pcmcat367
test_term, features, ~ENERGY STAR
test_term, brand_facet, Brand~GE
```

Comment: You have a very weird serialized data. Why don't you create a udf where you can apply your operations cleanly.

Comment: You actually have to first split at ^ to get all the facets and then foreach facets, split on "=" to get the value, right?

Comment: @debarshi - yes and I just updated my code to do the split at ^.  Now I need to get the output updated to my desired output

Comment: Why not split it with "=" and then flatten it. I would actual recommend you to write a udf, It would make your code cleaner

Comment: can I spit it using Regular Expression?? @jKraut